# Highcharts in Angular html

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Bonjour,

I'm having a problem introducing the Hihgcharts library to my Angular project.
Indeed I have a series of errors that just happened.
From what the error says, I have the impression that I don't have the Highchart module, yet it's in there.

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';
```

console.log

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'Highcharts' since it isn't a known property of
'highcharts-chart'.
1. If 'highcharts-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'Highcharts' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'highcharts-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    <div class="graphic">
        <highcharts-chart
        [ERROR ->][Highcharts] = "Highcharts"
        [option] = "chartOptions"
        style="height: 150px; margin: 2"): ng:///MlsModule/GraphicComponent.html@11:8 Can't bind to 'option'
since it isn't a known property of 'highcharts-chart'.
1. If 'highcharts-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'option' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'highcharts-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
        <highcharts-chart
        [Highcharts] = "Highcharts"
        [ERROR ->][option] = "chartOptions"
        style="height: 150px; margin: 2px;">
        <!-- <div id="containe"): ng:///MlsModule/GraphicComponent.html@12:8 'highcharts-chart' is not a
known element:
1. If 'highcharts-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'highcharts-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
to suppress this message. ("
    </div>
    <div class="graphic">
        [ERROR ->]<highcharts-chart
        [Highcharts] = "Highcharts"
        [option] = "chartOptions" "): ng:///MlsModule/GraphicComponent.html@10:8 Error: Template parse
errors: Can't bind to 'Highcharts' since it isn't a known property of
'highcharts-chart'.
1. If 'highcharts-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'Highcharts' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'highcharts-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    <div class="graphic">
        <highcharts-chart
        [ERROR ->][Highcharts] = "Highcharts"
        [option] = "chartOptions"
        style="height: 150px; margin: 2"): ng:///MlsModule/GraphicComponent.html@11:8 Can't bind to 'option'
since it isn't a known property of 'highcharts-chart'.
1. If 'highcharts-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'option' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'highcharts-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
        <highcharts-chart
        [Highcharts] = "Highcharts"
        [ERROR ->][option] = "chartOptions"
        style="height: 150px; margin: 2px;">
        <!-- <div id="containe"): ng:///MlsModule/GraphicComponent.html@12:8 'highcharts-chart' is not a
known element:
1. If 'highcharts-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'highcharts-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
to suppress this message. ("
    </div>
    <div class="graphic">
        [ERROR ->]<highcharts-chart
        [Highcharts] = "Highcharts"
        [option] = "chartOptions"*
```

So I have to make nine diagrams. All the diagrams will be identical except for the data which will be there. Here's my code:

**graphic.compenent.ts**

```
export class GraphicComponent implements OnInit {
  
  chartOptions: {};
  
  @Input() graphicDatasObservable: Observable<any>;
  @Input() status: string;
  @Input() data: any = [];

  Highcharts = Highcharts;


  constructor(private dataMlsService: DataMlsService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.graphicDatasObservable.subscribe( datas => {
      this.data = datas;
      console.log(this.data)
    });
    this.chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        type: 'area'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Random DATA'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Demo'
      },
      tooltip: {
        split: true,
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      series: this.data
    };
    }
```

**graphic.component.html**

```
 <div class="graphic">
        <highcharts-chart
        [Highcharts] = "Highcharts"
        [option] = "chartOptions"
        style="height: 150px; margin: 2px;">
        <!-- <div id="container" style="height: 150px; margin: 2px;"></div>        -->
        </highcharts-chart>    
    </div>
```

**service.ts**

```
bigChart(){
    return [{
        name: 'Asia',
        data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
      }]
}
```

**vente.component.ts**

```
 bigChart = [];
  
constructor(private dataMlsService: DataMlsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bigChart = this.dataMlsService.bigChart();

  }
```

**vente.component.html**

```
 <app-graphic [data]="bigChart"></app-graphic>
```

Comment: did you import the `ChartModule` in your module?

Comment: import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
In graphic.component.ts
import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';
in the parent module

Comment: unless I'm mistaken your module import should look like this "import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';"
source: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#hello-world-demo

Comment: I think you have imported ChartsModule app.module.ts file. You need to import it in your GraphicsModule. Read similar thread here. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/120#issuecomment-468532235

Comment: and import `import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';` into your module.

Comment: In my package-lock.json 
"angular-highcharts": {
      "version": "9.0.11",
      "resolved": "https://npm-registry.welcome-connect.fr/angular-highcharts/-/angular-highcharts-9.0.11.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Lpp7cGz2yE0QKIk9s2Vt2AtLBvBCdMpEXU+a9pUZQkaI4+zNbqkdT/mo7VRqMuZrshvQ8KTT8qd+BzYzVvZn/A=="
    }, And that 
"highcharts": {
      "version": "8.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://npm-registry.welcome-connect.fr/highcharts/-/highcharts-8.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Q124Lj+2+bVY2MKMd7d8uSVAmhZVzWgknUUzUBEC27S94dCyK6PBgahuwiMP/ET4w7qSFBBi4OC77ZUb0Vnuyg=="
    },

Comment: So I have the right bookstore?

Comment: i do npm install highcharts-angular --save and i include import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular'; but the problem persist.
 Can't bind to 'option' since it isn't a known property of 'highcharts-chart'.

Comment: Check this: https://therichpost.com/angular-8-9-10-highcharts-working-example/

Comment: That's exactly what I realized.

Comment: I will encourage you to try the official `highcharts-angular` wrapper. `angular-highcharts` is a 3rd party wrapper that, of course, might be helpful but it is not officially supported. Here you can find a link to the `highcharts-angular` docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular. If you decide to use it and you have any questions just let me know. Live example of the "area" series: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-area